# What does a 3-parameter index of a matrix refer to? (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I am experimenting with NumPy and matrices in python.

If I have an `identity_matrix` of length 4 (4x4):

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I know that `identity_matrix[0]` will output the first row, and `identity_matrix[0,1]` would output the second element of the first vector of the matrix.

Now what does the indexing **`identity_matrix[[2,2,0]]`** refer to? Please tell me what each index number represents. Also, why with the double square brackets? The output of this results in the following matrix:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: [Integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

Comment: the inner brackets define a list.  In indexing the distinction between list and tuple is important.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**:

What you are creating is a new array, which consists of the "rows" of your identiy matrix. I.e.:

`identity_matrix[[2,2,0]]` equals to a new array of lenght 3 (as `[2,2,0]` has length 3) with two times the row indexed by 2 (i.e. row 3) and one time the row indexed by 0 (i.e. row 1).

Hence, you get:

```
    [[0. 0. 1. 0.] (row 3 of identity matrix ,i.e. identity_matrix[2])
     [0. 0. 1. 0.] (row 3 of identity matrix, identity_matrix[2])
     [1. 0. 0. 0.]] (row 1 of identity matrix, identity_matrix[0])
```

*Reference:*

https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Comment: Just noticed it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

identity_matrix[row_number] will you single row vector, if you want to get multiple rows using single line statement, you can do identity_matrix[[first_row_index, second_row_index, ...]]